# Jenkins Build Periodically - Schedule

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking to build periodically every 15 minutes. I have looked online and I am using this schedule: `*/15 * * * *`

Jenkins is telling me to spread load evenly by using `H/15 * * * *` rather than `*/15 * * * *`

Could someone tell me the difference between using `H` instead of `*`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. From the ***Build Triggers*** → *Build periodically* → *Schedule* → [image] inline help:

> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible. For example, using `0 0 * * *` for a dozen daily jobs will cause a large spike at midnight. In contrast, using `H H * * *` would still execute each job once a day, but not all at the same time, better using limited resources.
>
> The H symbol can be used with a range. For example, `H H(0-7) * * *` means some time between 12:00 AM (midnight) to 7:59 AM. You can also use step intervals with `H`, with or without ranges.
>
> The `H` symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project.
>
> Beware that for the day of month field, short cycles such as `*/3` or `H/3` will not work consistently near the end of most months, due to variable month lengths. For example, `*/3` will run on the 1st, 4th, …31st days of a long month, then again the next day of the next month. Hashes are always chosen in the 1-28 range, so `H/3` will produce a gap between runs of between 3 and 6 days at the end of a month. (Longer cycles will also have inconsistent lengths but the effect may be relatively less noticeable.)
>
> Empty lines and lines that start with `#` will be ignored as comments.
>
> In addition, `@yearly`, `@annually`, `@monthly`, `@weekly`, `@daily`, `@midnight`, and `@hourly` are supported as convenient aliases. These use the hash system for automatic balancing. For example, `@hourly` is the same as `H * * * *` and could mean at any time during the hour. `@midnight` actually means some time between 12:00 AM and 2:59 AM.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> # every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
> H/15 * * * *
> # every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)
> H(0-29)/10 * * * *
> # once every two hours every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)
> H 9-16/2 * * 1-5
> # once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December
> H H 1,15 1-11 *
> ```