# How can I Schedule python script to run every day at specific time ? (except Windows schedule)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, python-requests

I have .py selenium scripts, I want to schedule the scrips to run daily at specific time.How can i do that ? windows platform

Comment: On linux, you can read about **crontab**

Comment: There are many third party applications on windows too

Comment: something like this? http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: What operating system will be used to run the Python script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to do something at the same time every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088037/python-script-to-do-something-at-the-same-time-every-day)

Comment: I am using Windows Platform

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you see something like [APScheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a CI mechanism like `Jenkins` or `Travis CI`? These CI tools will give you a perfect mechanism of running your tests, specifically on a specific time or minute of day.

This post talks about scheduling in detail - [Jenkins Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117718/jenkins-build-periodically-schedule).

Once you've scheduled your tests, you can check them manually or just configure them to send you emails once the build is run for the day.